# Has a micro-burst or wind shear caused fatalities on takeoff?

Tags: safety, takeoff, accident-statistics, extreme-weather

Delta **Flight 191** at Dallas-Fort Worth (1985), TANS Perú **Flight 204** in Peru (2005), FedEx Express **Flight 80** in Japan (2009), and Eastern Air Lines **Flight 66** at New York's JFK, are all examples of aircraft fatalities due to wind shear or micro-bursts during approach.

Have there been any ***airliner*** fatalities due to micro-bursts or wind shear on ***takeoff***?

[image]
 [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_shear)

UPDATE: As a hobby, I have spent my life following aircraft accidents. At the outset of this question, I was unaware and doubted any such occurrences had happened. The answers have certainly been an eye opener and shows the breath of knowledge this group has.

So far:

```
Canadair C-4 Argonaut three crew and 29 passengers killed
Pan Am Flight 759 all 145 on board and 8 on the ground killed
Spantax CV-990 crash of EC-BNM off Arlanda (1970)
Continental Flight 426, Denver, (1975)
Continental Flight 63, Tucson, (1977)
United Flight 663, Denver, (1984)
(possibly - AeroméxicoFlight 2431) (2018)
```

Comment: The first example in the [Wikipedia article on microbursts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microburst#Danger_to_aircraft) states ["...crash occurred ... when a ... four-engined Canadair C-4 Argonaut airliner ... crashed into a tree on departure ... three crew and 29 passengers were killed"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1956_Kano_Airport_BOAC_Argonaut_crash).   The fourth example is ["Pan Am Flight 759 ... crashed ... after being forced down by a microburst shortly after takeoff. All 145 on board and 8 people on the ground were killed."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_Am_Flight_759)

Comment: Does the [1970 Spantax CV-990 crash of EC-BNM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1970_Spantax_CV-990_crash) off Arlanda count?

Comment: Probably a bit early to be sure, but it seems yesterday's [Aeroméxico Connect Flight 2431](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2018/07/31/aeromexico-plane-crashes-near-durango-mexico-soon-take-off/) suffered this issue on take-off.

Comment: I had the same thought... interesting.

Comment: Have you done any research at the NTSB Aviation Accident database?  https://www.ntsb.gov/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/index.aspx

Comment: AeroMexico might have just made an entry to the list.

Answer (score 16):

One (of several) incidents that I remember was [Pan Am Flight 759](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_Am_Flight_759). It encountered windshear after takeoff from New Orleans' Moisant Airport July 9, 1982 and crashed, killing all aboard and several on the ground.

Comment: *"One (of several) incidents"*... what others are there?

Comment: Cursory googling results in a report by University of Chicago’s Dr. Ted Fujita and Dr. Horace Byers discussing the matter.  Takeoff related incidents from that: Continental Airlines Flight 426, Denver, 1975; Continental Airlines Flight 63, Tucson, 1977; United Airlines Flight 663, Denver, 1984.